# Package for showing all possible CSS values in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: css, autocomplete, sublimetext2, sublimetext

With the basic Sublime Text 2 build, I am getting CSS value autocompletion *only* when I type the first letter of the value, as seen in the image below.

[image: Basic CSS autocompletion]

However, I've been watching the Tuts HTML+CSS web tutorials ([here is an example video](https://courses.tutsplus.com/courses/30-days-to-learn-html-css/lessons/the-basics-of-typography)), and his Sublime Text build shows all possible CSS for a given attribute. Below is a screenshot from the linked example video.

[image: Display of all possible CSS values for a given attribute]

My question is **what setting or package allows for the display of all possible CSS values for a given attribute?**

Comment: [**This method**](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/how-to-automatically-pop-up-the-value-of-a-attribute/18548/5) will work if you want to add completions that are not available via SublimeText or plugins. Also, I'm working on a [**CustomCompletions**](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/solved-possible-to-launch-custom-autocomplete-on-modified-or-include-word-separators-on-query-completions/18942/8) plugin that allows users & developers to easily define their own completions for particular scopes, files, extensions, & directories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No additional packages or specific settings were needed to solve this issue. The Ctrl/Cmd+Space keyboard shortcut natively displays all possible completions.

Comment: Per knod's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36558972), Ctrl+Space is the current default completion shortcut on both Mac and Windows.

Comment: The only problem with Ctrl+Space is that it's not context sensitive. It provides ALL available completions as based on some sort of aggregated list of completions - instead of just providing the ones specifically for the property being completed.

Answer (score 3):

Try different plugins through [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/).

Specifically trying these may work for you:

- [CSS Completions](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/CSS%20Completions)
- [Emmet CSS Snippets](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Emmet%20Css%20Snippets)
- [CSS Extended Completions](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/CSS%20Extended%20Completions) (requires `ctrl/cmd + space`)

Comment: agreed, I wasn't aware of `Ctrl+Space` (Mac OSX) which works natively

Answer (score 0):

There is no package needed in Sublime Text 2 to display all possible completions, e.g. all possible values for a CSS property, but LaceLafontaine's answer is no longer current. `Cmd+Space` doesn't work on Macs, partially because it's a shortcut for a spotlight search.

Currently the shortcut to display the completions in OSX is `Ctrl+Space`. I believe it's the same for both Mac and PC. The issue was discussed here: https://github.com/processing/processing/issues/2699

Answer (score 0):

**Linux Users**

For me it worked when I config using this:

```
"auto_complete_triggers":
[
  {
    "characters": ": ",
    "selector": "source.css",
  },
],
```

And then you use `Space` as trigger.
There is an additional space before every value, but [Minify](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Minify) or [HTML-CSS-JS Prettify](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/HTML-CSS-JS%20Prettify) will delete all these spaces