# How to get autocomplete in Sublime text

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext

When I write overflow, How can I get this "panel" or "list" or something like this image that offers me words to combine with overflow.

[image]

I found solution ctrl+space but that doesn't give me just that(auto,hidden..),that gives me list of all selectors that exist.

I am using windows.

Comment: I think you will need an external package for this. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24894201/package-for-showing-all-possible-css-values-in-sublime-text-2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Package for showing all possible CSS values in Sublime Text 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24894201/package-for-showing-all-possible-css-values-in-sublime-text-2)

Comment: note that this bug will be fixed in the next release of ST3 (https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/issues/690). You can follow the instructions in the readme of that repo if you want to update your CSS package early to fix the bug without waiting for a release.