# How can I get CSS properties or Attributes automatically suggested in Sublime 3?

Tags: css

In Sublime 3, how can I get all available values(attribute) for a property after typing in the property in CSS?

```
ol.iit a:link {
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 1px 0px 1px 0px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow:
}
```

For example, lets say that I have an `overflow` prop and I want to see the possible values while typing in sublime text 3.

Comment: While this talks about Sublime 2, it might apply to Sublime 3 [**Package for showing all possible CSS values in Sublime Text 2?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24894201/package-for-showing-all-possible-css-values-in-sublime-text-2) - Also, have you tried asking on the sublime forums if there is any packages needed to get the feature you are looking for or if it is native?

Answer (score 0):

I think this package you need to install then it will work well.
[Click Here to get link](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/CSS3_Syntax)

there are some other packages which will help you like

1) Emmet CSS Snippets

2) CSS Completions

[Click here to get another solution](https://bumbu.github.io/making-emmet-autocompletion-work-with-scss-in-sublime-text/)